# Eating Apples and saying Chakal Tapuhin in Shabbat Yom Tov or Rosh Hashana

Tags: shabbat, minhag, yom-tov, rosh-hashanah-new-year

There is a custom to eat apples on Shabbat, as well as saying (Hakal Tapuchin) "apple field Kaddishin". On Shabbat that falls on Yom Tov, as well as on Shabbat that falls on Rosh Hashanah, do we establish this custom, and also do we say the parts in Aramaic that mention "Hakal Tapuchin Kaddishin"? Are there any Shabbat that this custom is not applicable?

Comment: I would guess many, many more Jews make a point of eating apples on rosh hashana, whether or not it falls on shabbat, than do so on a regular shabbat.

Comment: @JoelK And what about Yom Tov? What about saying the Aramit chapter?